# Make a button to control both AC and 12V DC light

Tags: switching

I want to make a button which control both ac and dc light

When button is on

If there is Electricity
Then AC bulb will be on

Else

DC bulb will be on

And if button is off both ac ane dc bulbs should be off

Comment: Please post more details, like what are those lights, how powerfull are they?

Comment: Ac bulb is 13 volt led and dc bulb is small led bulb upto 13 watt

Comment: the button actually has nothing to do with it, any button in series with the supply will work, the hard part is what to do to get the dc bulb not to flicker.

Comment: Can you put a black heatshrink  over a 5mm photo diode into 10M and cap and not pickup daylight? Then switch DC lamp ON.  both enabled by one power switch. Power from AC goes to an OPTO couple to detect switch is ON with 325Vpk with suitable power R.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase your question:

> When the button is pressed a light should turn on. If mains is available the AC light should turn on. Otherwise the DC backup lamp should turn on. When the button is released the light(s) should turn off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFzyd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A mains light priority lighting circuit.*

How it works:

- Pressing SW1, a two-pole switch, will connect LAMP1 to the AC supply. It will also connect the LED lamp, D1, to the DC supply for a moment.
- If AC is present then RLY1 will be energised and D1 will turn off.
- If AC is not present or is lost while the button is pressed then the LED lamp will turn on.

If your AC voltage is mains then this circuit can be dangerous. SW1 would have to be high quality with excellent separation between the two contacts with no chance of a short circuit between the contacts.

RLY1 would have an AC coil with a voltage rating to match the AC supply.

Comment: Big problem.  You can't mix high and low voltage circuits in the same junction boxes and yokes unless  the low voltage system is handled *entirely* in Class I wiring methods (i.e. installed exactly the same way as AC mains curcuits, same rules etc.)  NEC Article 725.

Answer (score 0):

### No practical way to have 12V and 120V on the same switch

Here's what you're up against.

> **NEC 725.136 (A) General.** Cables and conductors of Class 2 and Class 3 circuits shall not be placed in any cable, cable tray, compartment, enclosure, manhole, outlet box, device box, raceway, or similar fitting with conductors of electric light, power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm circuits, and medium-power network-powered broadband communications circuits unless permitted by 725.136(B) through (I).

So the problem is you can't have both AC and DC land on the same yoke.  Oh, they make DPDT switches that are UL-Listed for mains AC ... but they're not cheap.

Now, there is one exception: And that's if the entire low-voltage system is handled in Class 1 wiring methods.  But things are getting rather silly at this point: You're carrying 4 current-carrying conductors all over the place, running a whole lot of /4 cable (or dual /2).  You can't use the equipment safety ground (bare conductor) for a DC current return, sorry.

However that pushes you into the expensive DPST switches. Remember, you can't use RU-Recognized *components* for AC mains wiring installations from places like Digi-Key or Mouser : you must use UL-Listed *equipment* from places like Greybar or Platt or your friendly neighborhood electrical supply (or Home Depot).

You have a great deal more latitude *inside* a light fixture.

### Run the controls in entirely DC.  Switch the AC at the lamp.

Now you are running only DC to the switches.  You can do more complicated stuff like 3-way or smart switches, because you're not dragging around two voltage systems.

Note this setup works very similar to Transistor's above, except that the switch doesn't switch AC, the DC switched current *pulls in* AC.

As a result you are only bringing AC to the lights, rather than carrying it around to switches.

When AC power is on, the DC switched supply operates as both control and DC light supply -- it operates relay 2, which pulls in the AC power -- and AC power operates relay 1, the "knockout relay" to remove the DC light, just as in Transistor's design.

When AC power is off, the DC switched supply lights the light.  It tries and fails to bring in the AC lighting, but it doesn't work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faJ2Vt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, the knockout relay could be centralized: a big knockout relay which provides a DC lighting power system that is "energized when AC off".  If you carried that to the light with the AC power, you could have a DPDT relay operate both sources.  Further, this "energized when AC off" DC power could be a separate DC system that could be wired under the exception above.